# Could someone help me about this hearing : sanctions resolution has/have

Tags: grammatical-number, modifiers, listening

Could someone help me about **[this hearing](http://fast-uploader.com/file/7012194786334/)**?

From 0:24～，she ( the U.S ambassador to the United Nations, Samantha Power ) is
saying

“This resolution, if it passes, is nearly unprecedented in many respects as it’s the toughest, sanctions and resolutions that have been put forward in, in more than 2 decades.”

Should my hearing be correct, I would think the latter part of the sentence would not make sense to me, personally, I guess.

Or since from the ery first, am I wrong?

Or Sould I be correct about hearing this, what this part, **sanctions and resolutions that have been put forward in, in more than 2 decades.** might mean???? She said this because she wanted to "emphasize" that there had been
sanctions and resolutions over the 2 decades but they were actually not effectie at all?

Kindly let me thank you so much in advance.

Sincerely

Comment: If this was an audio recording I would interpret that as her simply repeating the word "in" because she was tripping over what to say next, and it should just have been "it's the toughest sanctions and resolutions that have been put forward in more than 2 decades." which could be reworded to "In over 20 years, nobody has suggested tougher sanctions and resolutions than these ones."

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Since it seems to me, she might have "paused", a bit,  after haing said the word "toughest", it is a bit vexing me to understand. By the way, this source is NPR. Thank you anyway.

Comment: "... it's the toughest sanctions resolution that has been put forward in more than two decades" - "sanctions" used adjectivally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's do an answer that goes beyond correcting what you thought you heard...

> "... it's the toughest sanctions resolution that has been put forward
>   in more than two decades" -

"sanctions" used adjectivally.

"sanctions resolution" = resolution relating to sanctions, either imposing them (as here) or lifting them.

"*has* been put forward" -- singular "has" to agree with singular "resolution"

P.S. I commend you for listening to Robert Siegel on NPR. He is one of the most articulate and intelligent radio news anchors in America today.

Comment: Great! I thought too "didn't she say" "has"? but since the idea sanctions used as an adjective didn't come up I skipped deliberatley... a very good answer to have woken me up! Thank you with my poor Engkish.